# unused argument (lex.order = FALSE) in boxplot function

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, I am getting the following error from the boxplot function when I run the example in Help.

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
Error in deparse(...) : unused argument (lex.order = FALSE)
```

The same function runs fine in R Console.

I have cleared my Global Environment.  These are the only packages that are attached.

```
search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     
"package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
[6] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         
"package:base"
```

I have tried searching for lex.order argument but haven't had much success.  I have also tried rerunning the function with a newly restarted RStudio with the same error message.

My R is version 3.4.0 and Rstudio is 1.0.143 if it helps

Comment: `lex.order` is a parameter to `interaction` for working out interaction terms. But that's base R, and so is `boxplot` (in the graphics package). Have these got out of sync in your RStudio? What do you get for packageVersion("base") and packageVersion("graphics")? What does traceback() say after that error?

Comment: thanks so much for this and sorry for the delayed reply.  You are right on the sync issue.  I'm seeing packageVersion('base') = 3.3.2 & packageVersion('graphics') = 3.4.0  Is there something I can do to resync this?

Comment: Try RStudio support? http://community.rstudio.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  At least I know where to start now