# R Vioplot error from deparse() when using formula

Tags: r, plot, formula

In Rstudio, I get the error: ***"Error in deparse(...) : unused argument (lex.order = FALSE)"*** when trying to use the `vioplot()` function with a formula [as demonstrated here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vioplot/vignettes/violin_formulae.html). A reproducible example here:

```
x <- rnorm(50, 0.5, 0.1)
y <- sample(c('A','B'), 50, replace=T)

vioplot(y~x)
vioplot(x~y)
```

Both of these calls of vioplot return the error: `Error in deparse(...) : unused argument (lex.order = FALSE)`

The only other question I could find with a similar problem using a formula was for the boxplot function and [can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426188/unused-argument-lex-order-false-in-boxplot-function) It seemed that the issue might've been a result of base and graphics versions being out of sync but mine appear correct (`packageVersion("graphics")` and `packageVersion("base")` both return `3.3.2`).

Running `traceback()` after the error gives me:

```
9: deparse(...)
8: sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain), ...)
7: gettextf("argument '%s' is not used (yet)", arg)
6: .NotYetUsed(deparse(...), error = FALSE)
5: split.default(mf[[response]], mf[-response], drop = drop, sep = sep, 
       lex.order = lex.order)
4: split(mf[[response]], mf[-response], drop = drop, sep = sep, 
       lex.order = lex.order)
3: vioplot(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response], drop = drop, sep = sep, 
       lex.order = lex.order), xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, names = names, 
       add = add, ann = ann, horizontal = horizontal, side = side, 
       ...)
2: vioplot.formula(x ~ y)
1: vioplot(x ~ y)
```

I can get around this by making the plots one after another for the conditions in y, but the formatting is weird with only one tick mark for the first condition. I'm sure I could work around it but I'm curious why the formula isn't working.

The workaround example looks like:

```
vioplot(x[y=='A'], at = 1, xlim = c(0,3), ylim = c(0.2,0.8))
vioplot(x[y=='B'], at = 2, xlim = c(0,3), ylim = c(0.2,0.8), add = T)
```

[image]

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

`sessionInfo()` included below:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.15.6

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] vioplot_0.3.5     zoo_1.8-2         sm_2.2-5.4        PRROC_1.3.1       pheatmap_1.0.12   philentropy_0.4.0
[7] ggplot2_2.2.1     reshape_0.8.7    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3         lattice_0.20-35    digest_0.6.15      crayon_1.3.4       grid_3.3.2        
 [6] plyr_1.8.4         gtable_0.2.0       scales_0.5.0       pillar_1.4.3       rlang_0.4.4       
[11] lazyeval_0.2.1     rstudioapi_0.7     labeling_0.3       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_3.3.2       
[16] munsell_0.5.0      pkgconfig_2.0.1    colorspace_1.3-2   tibble_2.1.3
```

Comment: `vioplot(x~y)` works for me.

Comment: First thing I see is your R version is 3.3.2. Try updating!!!

Comment: Thanks Eric! Updated to R v4.0.3 and it seems to being playing more nicely. If you submit as an answer I'll accept it.